# Should I be using direct function calls instead of event handlers here?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm working in Actionscript3, building a MMO-like game, I'm in charge of the UI, among other things. I use Events for a lot of my workflow, but my partner was suggesting that I use direct function calls for my UI assets instead. Here's an example:

1. I created a **ColorChooser** class that we're using to re-color parts of a user's avatar.
2. When you click on a color, the **ColorChooser** reads the pixel (of a color spectrum image) clicked and dispatches an event (**ColorChooser.COLOR_CHOSEN**).
3. My **AvatarDesigner** class is listening for this event.
4. When the event gets dispatched, the handler event in **AvatarDesigner** reads **(e.target as ColorChooser).chosenColor** and applies that color to the selected part of the avatar.

My partner was suggesting that instead I:

1. Give **ColorChooser** the instance of its parent **AvatarDesigner** object (**_avatarDesigner**).
2. When a color is clicked, read the pixel clicked (**var chosenColor:uint**) and call **_avatarDesigner.colorAvatar(chosenColor)** from within the **ColorChooser** object.

Now, with most of my UI I'm using events so that I can keep assets like dropdown menus, buttons, textareas separate and re-usable. I imagine that we'll re-use this ColorChooser object for other things (ObjectDesigner, WallpaperDesigner, BuildingDesigner). He said that it'd be better to add a condition within ColorChooser each time I use it for something else, so perhaps like:

```
private function colorClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var chosenColor:uint = *the color chosen (bitmapdata.getpixel());*
    switch(parent){
        case AvatarDesigner:    (parent as AvatarDesigner).colorChosen(chosenColor); 
                                break;
        case ObjectDesigner:    (parent as ObjectDesigner).colorChosen(chosenColor); 
                                break;
        case WallpaperDesigner: (parent as WallpaperDesigner).colorChosen(chosenColor); 
                                break;
        case BuildingDesigner:  (parent as BuildingDesigner).colorChosen(chosenColor); 
                                break;
    }
}
```

Or something like that (maybe instead of checking parent, checking a string "type" in the constructor or something). This seems strange to me since I'd have to go back in and add a case each time it's used somewhere else. Whereas with events it can fire off it's event and have it handled or not handled regardless of what its parent is. Some of his reasoning is:

- Events should only be used for asynchronous events or input (mouse, keyboard)
- Dispatched events and listeners take up more cpu
- Direct function calls are faster since it's part of the current thread and not dispatched and handled at a slightly different time
- Actionscript3 and Away3D (used for 3D) don't ever use events in this way

Whereas I feel that events are appropriate for reasons such as:

- Allows objects to stay totally independent of their parents making them more reusable
- I don't think dispatched events and listeners take up more CPU (e.g. since any given Sprite is dispatching many events at any given time like ENTER_FRAME, MOUSE_OUT, ADDED_TO_STAGE) without seeing a performance hit
- The slight asynchronicity isn't important if order-dependant tasks happen in the listener after the dispatchEvent
- Away3D does use them in this way, I think, after digging around their API a bit.

Can anyone shine some light on this? Could it possibly be worth hard-coding in a new logic condition in, say, "ShinyButton" every time I use this asset in a different type of parent? Even if events and listeners are using CPU, wouldn't adding conditions like this make it a bit spaghetti-ish?

Also, for the life of me I can't find an Actionscript3 best practices for when Events are good or bad, and why. Also, I'd love if any knows how Events are used on the low-level.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You're right, your friend is talking nonsense. Any performance gains with his approach will be negligible and as you've anticipated the tight coupling will become a problem when you want to reuse your component.

Comment: Thanks for the input, net.uk.sweet

Comment: A good reference for best practice might be to look at how some of the components in the Flex framework are structured. You'll find events are heavily used to avoid tight-coupling of different components. I'd be surprised if you found anything akin to your friend's suggested switch statement in there ;)

Comment: Thanks, will do. He also suggested that since we don't plan on releasing our project as open source, that tight-coupling is alright; our parts wouldn't need to be import friendly for others. My view was that while others won't be using our objects, that I'll be using them repeatedly around our own project.

Comment: You're absolutely right again. Tight-coupling in your project will be a barrier to reuse and make maintenance by you (or the next developer) more difficult. You know what you're talking about, it just sounds like you need the confidence to tell your friend he's wrong. If you want, I'll come round and tell him ;).

Comment: Haha, thanks for the vote of confidence. It's not so much a matter of who's wrong or right, but what's best for the project. We were worried that using Events as heavily as I am might be costing us CPU or RAM or something, or simply be going against some sort of coding guidelines/standards. And thanks for the tip about Flex, I'll dig around.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should be more measured in my answers. I'll rephrase it by saying that, in this case, I think you're right.

Comment: No problem, thanks again. On a different note, I cross posted this to reddit, and someone suggested that parents should implement an interface with a `colorChosen' method. Does this sound better / more normal? Would this mean that anything I put colorChooser in would also have to use the interface? (say, using events only, if I add it to an empty sprite for only display purposes; the event'll still fire, but I won't be forced to handle it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, I think you are right and your friend is wrong. Any perceived performance gains (if any) will be negligible and the [tight-coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) introduced will, as you anticipate correctly, make it difficult to reuse your component in other situations and make your project more difficult to maintain as a whole.

ActionScript is an event-based asynchronous language and you'll be doing your friend a favour if you encourage him to embrace it rather than fight it!

To answer your question about best-practices for ActionScript 3.0 development, I think you could do worse than look at the structure of some of the components of the Flex framework. These were developed by Adobe engineers and, as such, can be considered a demonstration of what is considered best-practice. You'll find heavy use of events to avoid tight-coupling between different components or component actors and minimal use of the sort of [smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) code your friend is suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your different opinions are based on habits more than real reasons.

I would personnaly use the personnal event model which is the most open and flexible solution I have in mind.

But if you want to use callback functions with no need to go back to your `ColorChooser`, you can create an Interface like `IColorReceiver` with a required method called something like `applyColor(color:Color){};` (Speaking of programming best practices, you should be aware that method names are clearer with verbs like "applyColor" or "choseColor" instead of adjectives or names like "colorChosen" which doen't means lot)

Then in your `colorPicked(e:MouseEvent){}` method you make sure that `parent` implements `IColorReceiver`, and you call `applyColor(chosenColor);` with no other test than the one with `IColorReceiver`. It could also work with classic inheritance but require more code for less flexibility.

I do not provide code, but you seem to have a reasonable level so I'm confident. ;)

(hope my english is correct)

Comment: Hey there Pag, thanks for the input! That's interesting. Is there an example of an interface working like this that I could dig around in? Is this similar to a controller? Also, yes great point about using verbs. Thanks again

Comment: Also, yes I think habits play a big part. He's doing a lot of the 3D work, so he's interfacing directly with the Scene3D, the World xml, and whatnot. Doing UI and seeing how buttons work with events, it seems natural that I embraced events and that became natural to me. At the end of the day you'd say that both are fine?

Comment: I would say that if the personnal event model works fine, use it ! And I'd say that in the beginning of the day :) But don't forget to write a doc about it !